# Contribution of an asset's variance to portfolio variance

Tags: portfolio-optimization, modern-portfolio-theory, mean-variance, derivation

How can an **asset's variance**, $\sigma_i^2$, be shown to contribute to **portfolio variance**, $\sigma_p^2$?

I was thinking of taking the derivative (first order conditions $\frac{\partial L_{\sigma_p^2}(w,\lambda)}{\partial \sigma_i}$) of the Lagrangean formulation of the minimum-variance portfolio's objective function, for example, but not sure if this is the right approach since the idea is to speculate *before optimization*, how an asset's variance will contribute to portfolio variance, based on that asset's stand-alone variance (or volatility) level. Besides, asset variances don't appear in the portfolio variance's Lagrangean.

A demonstrated derivation of the $\frac{\partial L_{\sigma_p^2}(w,\lambda)}{\partial \sigma_i}$ first order conditions might be marked best answer, but also open to alternative suggestions.

Answer (score 7):

In this answer, I am assuming that you want to keep correlations constant.

To begin with, note that the $N\times N$ covariance matrix $\Sigma$ with element $\Sigma_{i,j}=Cov(x_i,x_j)$ can be written as

$$
\Sigma = \mathbf{SRS}
$$

where $\mathbf{S}$ is a diagonal matrix of the simple volatilties $\sigma_i$, and $\mathbf{R}$ is the correlation matrix. Thus in a matrix sense,

$$
\frac{\partial \mathbf{\Sigma}}{\partial\sigma_i}=\frac{\partial\mathbf{SRS}}{\partial\sigma_i}=\frac{\partial\mathbf{S}}{\partial\sigma_i}\mathbf{RS}+\mathbf{SR}\frac{\partial\mathbf{S}}{\partial\sigma_i}
$$

The derivative of $\mathbf{S}$ with respect to $\sigma_i$ is a diagonal matrix of zeros, whose $i$th element is $1$. It is a *single-entry matrix* or a *selector matrix*, which we shall denote $\mathbf{E}_i$. For example, for $\mathbf{E}_2$ is

$$
\mathbf{E}_2=\begin{pmatrix}0&0&0&\ldots &0\\
0&1&0&\ldots &0\\
\ldots &\ldots &\ldots &\ldots &\ldots \\
0&0&0&\ldots &0\\\end{pmatrix}
$$

Hence,

$$
\frac{\partial\mathbf{\Sigma}}{\partial\sigma_i}=\mathbf{E}_i\mathbf{RS}+\mathbf{RS}\mathbf{E}_i  
$$

Thus, **the marginal impact of a *change in* (any) of the volatilities** on portfolio variance $v=\mathbf{w}^T\mathbf{\Sigma} \mathbf{w}$ can be computed as (after some algebra)

$$
\frac{\partial v}{\partial \mathrm{diag(S)}}=\mathbf{w}^T\frac{\partial \mathbf{\Sigma}}{\partial \mathrm{diag(S)}}\mathbf{w}=2\mathbf{w}\otimes \left(\mathbf{RSw}
\right)$$
where $\otimes$ denotes element wise multiplication, i.e. $x\otimes y = \mathrm{diag}(xy^T)$. Conveniently, this formulation returns all derivatives at once.

---

**Example**: With

$$
\mathbf{S}=\mathrm{diag}\begin{pmatrix}0.1&0.2&0.3\end{pmatrix}
$$
and
$$
\mathbf{R}=\begin{pmatrix}1 & 0.5 & 0.25 \\ 0.5 & 1 & 0.1 \\ 0.25 & 0.1 & 1\end{pmatrix}
$$
and a weight vector

$$
\mathbf{w}=\begin{pmatrix}0.2 & 0.3 & 0.5\end{pmatrix}^T
$$

we find

$$
\frac{\partial v}{\partial \mathrm{diag(S)}}=2\mathbf{w}\otimes \left(\mathbf{RSw}
\right)=2\begin{pmatrix}.2\\.3\\.5\end{pmatrix}\otimes\begin{pmatrix}0.0875\\0.085\\0.161\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}0.035\\0.051\\0.161\end{pmatrix}
$$

Thus, for example, the sensitivity of the portfolio variance with respect to the first volatility is 0.035.

---

With a bit more of algebra, you can find the impact of standalone vols on any portfolio optimisation solution, e.g. the MVP. Using the results from above and the fact that $\sigma_{MVP}=\frac{1}{\mathbf{1}^T{\Sigma^{-1} 1}}$ and the knowledge that $\mathbf{\Sigma}^{-1}=\mathbf{S}^{-1}\mathbf{R}^{-1}\mathbf{S}^{-1}$.

Comment: While this gives the derivative of portfolio variance with respect to individual variance, the results can sometimes be negative. When an investor asks "what is the contribution of asset A's risk to your total risk?", if you reply with a negative number, you're fired. The derivative here gives the _marginal_ contribution to risk, just like the Lagrangian 'solution' to this problem.

Comment: I would argue that negative portfolio weights may result in negative derivatives and are perfectly normal, think *risk reducing exposure* or hedges. In that regard, I think the metric‘s goal needs to be defined properly. Also, I think the  Original question was about the impact of $\sigma_i$, not the $i$th asset‘s contribution to overall risk, no?

Comment: are the elements in the vector $2\mathbf{w}\otimes \left(\mathbf{RSw}
\right)$ unitless? what does a 0.035 sensitivity of the portfolio variance really mean, besides being numerically relative to the other elements in the same vector? also, does this vector's sum, norm, re-scaling, etc have any meaning or usefulness

Comment: You guys are right: I have produced the marginal impact of a change in $\sigma_i$, not its contribution *per se*. Then,  I’d second @steveo'america ‘s answer below

Comment: Negativity of the result here has nothing to do with shorting. Imagine two assets with unit variances and correlation $\rho$. Then the first element of $w \cdot (RS w)$ will be $w_1 (w_1 + \rho w_2)$. If $\rho < 0$, this can be negative even if all $w_i > 0$. That said, I did not read the problem properly, and you have answered the question as asked, computing the derivative. I would say, however, that derivative is not actually of interest.

Comment: whether or not this answer is showing the marginal impact of a change in $\sigma_i$, could I know its source?

Comment: @steveo'america, yes: If an assets (more exactly: a *position's*) contribution to overall variance is sought, and if the contributions are to be positive and are to be summing to total variance, then your answer is the correct one. In that case, I suggest you *could* replace the matrix square root equation with (maybe) an Eigen decomposition and show that the squared elements of the resulting vector sum to total variance. If, on the other hand, the *sensitivity* of the portfolio volatility with respect to an individual asset volatility is sought after, my response would be correct.

Comment: @develarist : Maybe you could clarify in your question which of the two ideas you had in mind originally :-) . Also: The results shown are derived by a bit of linear algebra and matrix calculus.

Comment: @Kermittfrog yes, any square root of $\Sigma$ will yield the decomposition of risk. Many of them, however, lack the 'equivariance' property. For example, if you use the Cholesky square root of $\Sigma$, then re-arrange the order of the assets in your vector, the results are not reordered in the same way. In this case it is hard to identify the elements of $\Sigma^{1/2}\vec{w}$ with the assets themselves.

Comment: @steveo'america understood - thanks for that pointer.

Answer (score 3):

The Lagrangian 'solution' can yield *negative* contributions to portfolio risk, which is a bad look. An alternative definition is via the symmetric square root of the covariance, $\Sigma^{1/2}$. For portfolio $\vec{w}$ define
$$
\vec{r} = \Sigma^{1/2}\vec{w}.
$$
The norm of $\vec{r}$ is the volatility of the portfolio. Moreover, this definition is equivariant with respect to rotations of the asset space (using the Cholesky square root would not yield this property), and thus elementwise $\vec{r}$ can be identified with the individual assets. See also [no parity like risk parity](https://www.gilgamath.com/risk-parity.html).

Comment: could you start higher up because I don't know where $\Sigma^{1/2} w$ even comes from. what is that. or what is $\Sigma w$

Comment: $\Sigma^{1/2}$ is the _symmetric square root_ of $\Sigma.$ It is a symmetric matrix $A$ such that $AA = \Sigma$. Computed by `sqrtm` in matlab, for example. In contrast to the Cholesky square root, which is a lower triangular $A$ such that $AA^{\top} = \Sigma$.

Comment: but why would you multiply a covariance matrix by the portfolio weight vector to compute returns? what is $r$

Comment: The vector $\vec{r}$ has the property that $\vec{r}^{\top}\vec{r} = \sigma^2_p = \vec{w}^{\top}\Sigma\vec{w}$. (I should also mention you want to take the absolute value of $\vec{r}$ to avoid negative values. Doing so still gives this decomposition of total variance.)

Comment: so $r$ is not returns (still don't know what it is, besides its property), and $\Sigma^{1/2} w$ is not a modification of something ($\Sigma w$) that existed previously in MPT ($\Sigma w$ was never something in MPT)

Comment: Elements of $|\vec{r}|$ are the risk contribution of each asset to total portfolio risk. It is like an 'elementwise square root' of the portfolio variance. It is the quantity that you seek to compute. The answer.

Comment: can you spell out which formula you mean by "The Lagrangian 'solution' can yield negative contributions to portfolio risk". not sure what you're comparing your answer to

Comment: Sorry, I had misread the question, and was answering a question about Risk Parity, which has a deficient Lagrangian solution. That said, the derivative given by @kermittfrog can be negative due to negative correlation among the assets, as noted in my comment.

Comment: if $\vec{r} = \Sigma^{1/2}\vec{w}$ is a weighted sum of asset volatilities, then how can this answer be correct given that  portfolio variance is *not* simply a weighted sum of asset variance because it also requires a covariance/correlation term

Comment: @develarist: your question was how the asset's variance  contributes to the overall portfolio variance.  But the covariances will only come into play if TWO of the weights in the weight vector are non-zero. So, if  $w_x$ and $w_y$ were the weights of stock x and stock y, then it would be $w^2_{x} \times  var(x) + w^2_{y} \times var(y) + w_{x} \times w_{y} \times cov(x,y)$.

Comment: @develarist: I read your question but I didn't attempt to understand what steveo america or kermittfrog did once I realized the time I would need.  maybe someday when I have many hours. Therefore,  I have no idea if what I wrote above is at all related to r with the arrow on top of it. All I can say is that its the variance of a portfolio with those weights in those two stocks.

Comment: @steveo'america: I love your profile statement.