# Contribution to Mahalanobis Distance

Tags: volatility, statistics, correlation

I am using Mahalanobis Distance to measure abnormal behavior within a portfolio consisting of a handful of general asset types, and am trying to figure out how to decompose this measurement into marginal contributors on a granular level. My variables are as follows:

- $r_i$ is scalar, representing the return from asset $i$
- $\Sigma_{i,j}^{-1}$ is the $(i,j)$ element of the inverse covariance matrix ($\Sigma^{-1}$)
- $MD$ represents the Mahalanobis Distance value
- $MD_i$ represents the marginal contribution to Mahalanobis Distnace from asset $i$

I've already split it up into marginal contribution from each asset (done similarly as marginal contribution to portfolio volatility):
$$
MD_i = r_i\frac{\partial MD}{\partial r_i} = \frac{r_i\sum_j(r_j\Sigma^{-1}_{i,j})}{MD}
$$
But would like to split it up even further into individual volatility and correlation components. Below is my attempt at that:
\begin{align}
MD_i &= \frac{r_i\sum_j(r_j\Sigma^{-1}_{i,j})}{MD} \\
&= \frac{r_i^2\Sigma^{-1}_{i,i}}{MD} + \frac{r_i\sum_{j\neq i}r_j\Sigma^{-1}_{i,j}}{MD} \\
&= \underbrace{\frac{r_i^2\Sigma^{-1}_{i,i}}{MD}}_{\text{Volatility Component}_i} + \underbrace{\frac{r_ir_j\Sigma^{-1}_{i,j}}{MD} + \frac{r_ir_k\Sigma^{-1}_{i,k}}{MD} + \dots + \frac{r_ir_l\Sigma^{-1}_{i,l}}{MD}}_{\text{Correlation Component}_i} 
\end{align}
My logic is that if I split up all terms into those that:

1. Contain return data just from asset $i$ ($r_i^2$)
2. Contain return data from both assets $i$ and $j\neq i$ ($r_ir_j$)

Then I will have split up this marginal contribution into terms that pertain to volatility (1) and correlation (2). However, I've read a bit about how the inverse covariance matrix (precision matrix) and learned that each element contains data regarding volatilities  **and**  correlation, which makes me think that my attempt isn't valid.

Can anybody shed some light on whether my logic is indeed off, and perhaps how to go about accomplishing my goal?

Comment: Just added some bullets to the top to explain the symbols. Let me know if you need additional context/details.

Comment: In order to split this in a ‚marginal contribution‘ kind of way wrt to any parameter, you need a function that is homogeneous (degree = 1 if you want to apply your formula) in that parameter. What you *could* try is to see how the MD‘s vola and mu estimates react to your r values; after all they are only estimates, no?

Comment: The covariance matrix is empirically derived from the asset returns, and it isn't necessarily the sensitivity to the vol/mu that I'm caring about. At a high level, I understand MD to be a measure of abnormality in terms of the realized volatilities of each asset and the realized correlations between all assets. I want to be able to explain how volatility and correlation are each contributing to MD.

Comment: You could disentangle correlation and volatility by rewriting $\Sigma=SRS$ with $S$ the diagonal matrix of volatilities and $R$ the correlation matrix. This way you can easily calculate both derivatives (wrt to $S$ and $R$) see [matrix cookbook](http://www2.imm.dtu.dk/pubdb/edoc/imm3274.pdf) ,but I still do not think that the MD is a homogeneous function in those parameters; but I could be wrong in that assumption.

Comment: @Kermittfrog I like that idea, and appreciate the link! I'll look into it and update if I make progress.

Comment: I just gave it a bit more thought: Assuming zero $\mu_i$, the contribution of the volatility parameter $\sigma_i$ is simply the negative of the contribution of the corresponding $x_i$. If the MD is $f(x^T(SRS)^{-1}x)$ we can directly see that the correlation matrix is pre-/post multiplied by terms of the form $\frac{x_i}{\sigma_i}$.

Comment: Maybe I missed this, but how are you defining MD? Also, since MD is apparently non-negative, how would you feel about having negative contributions from some assets? See also: https://quant.stackexchange.com/a/59337/31456 .

Comment: @steveo'america I'm defining MD as $\sqrt{r^T\Sigma^{-1}r}$. I checked out your link and the subsequent "no parity like risk parity" link and am trying to understand it more fully. How do you differentiate between **contribution** and **marginal impact**?

Comment: It depends on the audience. A _marginal impact_ is just that: the change from an additional unit of the asset, but it can be negative, which is counterintuitive. A _contribution_, to me, sounds like it should sum up to the total (and be positive, in this case). There are identification problems, however.

Comment: @steveo'america I remember us having this discussion about *contribution* vs *marginal impact* a couple of months ago. Do you know whether there is some authoritative source on the definitions? Carol Alexander's Market Risk Analysis Volume IV defines  a *marginal VaR* as the sum of the weighted partial derivatives; this adds to total VaR and "[...] can be used to allocate _real_ capital which  [...] must add up." She also introduces incremental VaR via a 1st-order-Taylor approximation.

Comment: @steveo'america Another source I have at hand is the Credit Metrics documentation, quoting: "Where we define marginal risk to be the contribution of one asset to the total portfolio risk, others define it to be the marginal impact on portfolio risk of increasing an exposure by some small amount."

Comment: @Kermittfrog I am a mathematician by training; we don't use the word "marginal". However, I believe it is standard in economics for "marginal" to refer to the derivative. The fact that the marginal risk contributions add to the total risk is something of a coincidence, and one can exhibit other decompositions that have that property (such as the square root decomposition). I think it best to view the marginal decomposition as just derivatives, and recognize there is no unique sensible decomposition. I also feel that negative marginals are fishy.

Comment: If you've ever had a bigwig ask you "what is the contribution of each stock to your portfolio's risk?", and you had to tell them that, _e.g._, "AAPL contributes -0.38%", you would seek a better definition of risk contribution. Investors may not understand the higher order math, but they can smell B.S.

Comment: @steveo'america I understand your point of negative risk contribution not being intuitive, but how do you reconcile the following scenario: $P_A$ and $P_B$ are two identical portfolios save for the fact that $P_A$ has a 5% holding in cash while $P_B$ has a 5% holding in Stock $X$. As a result, $P_B$ has a lower volatility than $P_A$. Wouldn't it make sense to say that Stock $X$ has a negative contribution to risk in $P_B$?

Comment: @Ringleader this example has some serious flaws. Apparently $X$ is negatively correlated with portfolio $P_A$. As you add $X$ to $P_A$ continuously, the risk will decrease, hit a minimum, then start to increase again. The _marginal_ contribution to risk in $P_B$ from $X$ thus could be negative, zero, or positive. The fact that $P_B$ has lower risk than $P_A$ does *not* imply that the marginal contribution is negative! So does $X$ have negative contribution or not?

Comment: Moreover, in this case, $X$ has a negative marginal risk on portfolio $P_A$, since adding an infinitesimal amount lowers risk. How do you get negative risk from a stock you don't even hold!? Unfortunately, this is an issue with the symmetric square root definition as well...